# ImageView height and width become 0 when screen rotated while in camera

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera-intent

I am trying to build a simple photography app. When launched, the user is presented with a basic mainActivity that has a Toolbar and an imageView. The user presses an action button in the action bar which creates an intent that starts the camera app using `startActivityForResult()`. The picture that the user takes using the camera app is then returned to mainActivity. I get the size of both the image and the imageView and use them to calculate a scaling factor which I use to decode a smaller version of the bitmap, like this:

```
BitmapFactory.Options bitmapFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bitmapFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mImageFileLocation, bitmapFactoryOptions);
int actualCameraImageWidth = bitmapFactoryOptions.outWidth;
int actualCameraImageHeight = bitmapFactoryOptions.outHeight;

int heightScale = actualCameraImageHeight / imageViewHeight;
int widthScale = actualCameraImageWidth / imageViewWidth;

Integer factorToUse;

if (heightScale == widthScale) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "scales are the same: " + heightScale, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    factorToUse = heightScale;
} else {
    factorToUse = Math.min(heightScale, widthScale);
    Toast.makeText(this, "scales are DIFFERENT: " + factorToUse, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

bitmapFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = factorToUse;
bitmapFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

Bitmap reducedSizePhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mImageFileLocation, bitmapFactoryOptions);   //decode the image with that scale option set

imageView.setImageBitmap(reducedSizePhoto);
```

I then display that decoded bitmap in the imageView of mainActivity.

The app works great if the user keeps their device in the same orientation while they take a picture. However, if they press the action button and then change the orientation of their device while in the camera app then a RunTimeException is thrown with the following message `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.wescj.cameraapplication/com.wescj.cameraapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent {  }} to activity {com.wescj.cameraapplication/com.wescj.cameraapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero` and then a massive stack trace.

Using the debugger, I think I have traced the source of this error back to the fact that, for some reason, when the device orientation is changed while the user is in the camera app, the height and width of the imageView become 0, leading to a 'divide by 0' error.

I have tried everything I can think of to stop the app crashing if the orientation is changed when using the camera. I have searched the android documentation and looked at so many threads on stackOverflow. I have tried adding different xml attributes to the imageView, such as `adjustViewBounds` and `setScaleType`. I even tried using an intent on `onResultActivity()` to start mainActivity and display the image. But none of them worked. Can anyone shed any light on why the imageView dimensions become 0?

The full code can be seen at: https://github.com/Wes1324/CameraApplication/tree/action_bar_button

Thanks to anyone in advance that tries to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Trying adding **screenSize** to your activity

```
<Activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" ...>
```

and overriding so you can handle configuration changes by yourself

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

More info here: [Handling Configuration Changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)